# What is a "fine" lady

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, adjectives

I'm reading the book "the TRUE confessions of Charlotte Doyle" by the author Avi.
The main character, Charlotte, was called a "fine lady", what exactly did this mean? I'm guessing a well educated lady? What are some characteristics of a fine lady?
Please note Avi is an American author.

Comment: I think the best way to answer this question would be to read the rest of the book. As others have said in their answers, _fine_ is a very general word. Though it's usually regarded as a compliment (unless you happen to be a [numismatist](http://coins.ha.com/tutorial/coin-grading.s)), it could refer to looks, tastes, character, or all three, so only Avi would be able to furnish the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can mean anything, depending on the context. ***But*** broadly, when applied to a person, it means good in character or ability. The [FreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fine) has an entry for that

> fine - *Excellent in character or ability*

The example follows are: `a fine person; a fine writer.`

It can also mean beautiful and attractive! (The same page)

> good-looking; handsome

The example follows: `a fine young woman`.

Answer (score 3):

Could you provide more context?

I've seen this term mean two different things in literature:

- A woman who is a good person, sophisticated and charming, almost always rich and upper class, and preferably beautiful. Anna Karenina could have been described as a fine lady.
- A woman who is rich and lives luxuriously, i.e. a woman who has much "finery." This usage does not imply any particular goodness about her character; it only emphasizes her wealth and expensive tastes.